# Typescript Self Reference as Class Constructor

Tags: typescript

```
class Foo<T> {
    remake(){
        return new Foo<T>;
    }
    recast(){
        return this as any as Foo<Array<T>>
    }
}
```

I want to make Child class of `Foo` Class.
Child class should be referencing itself on `remake` and `recast`

also, If there has other syntax for change to generics of instance, it will be good to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `remake` using `this.constructor` and type it using the `this` type.  `recast` needs [higher-kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213) or a way of faking them, as below, and needs you to explicitly specify the type constructor for each subclass (it might be possible to infer this automatically with a native implementation of higher-kinded types).

```
// Matt's mini "type functions" library

const INVARIANT_MARKER = Symbol();
type Invariant<T> = { [INVARIANT_MARKER](t: T): T };

interface TypeFuncs<C, X> {}

const FUN_MARKER = Symbol();
type Fun<K extends keyof TypeFuncs<{}, {}>, C> = Invariant<[typeof FUN_MARKER, K, C]>;

const BAD_APP_MARKER = Symbol();
type BadApp<F, X> = Invariant<[typeof BAD_APP_MARKER, F, X]>;
type App<F, X> = [F] extends [Fun<infer K, infer C>] ? TypeFuncs<C, X>[K] : BadApp<F, X>;

// Example

const F_Foo = Symbol();
type F_Foo = Fun<typeof F_Foo, never>;
const F_Bar = Symbol();
type F_Bar = Fun<typeof F_Bar, never>;
interface TypeFuncs<C, X> {
    [F_Foo]: Foo<X>; 
    [F_Bar]: Bar<X>;
}

class Foo<T, F = F_Foo> {
    remake(): this {
        return new (<any>this.constructor)();
    }
    recast(): App<F, T[]> {
        return this as any as App<F, T[]>;
    }
}
class Bar<T, F = F_Bar> extends Foo<T, F> { }

let b = new Bar<number>();
let b2 = b.remake();
console.log(b2.constructor.name);  // Bar
let b3 = b.recast();  // Bar<number[]>
```

Comment: Cool type acrobatics :)

Comment: I copied your codes, and change `Invariant` and `TypeFuncs` to interface, because of `tslint`. `F_bar` occurred error. `TS2344: Type 'unique symbol' does not satisfy the constraint 'never'`. I using 2.9.2

Comment: Can't use generic to this.constructor, need to other way like `recast`

Comment: Re first comment: Please add the exact code you tried to the question.  Re second comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean at all.